# Issue with box-sizing: border-box on a <aside> element

Tags: html, css

I have an issue using box-sizing: border-box on a aside element.. screenshot provided below.

Here are the code snippets from my site:

HTML:

```
<aside>
     <h2 class="widgettitle">No active widgets</h2>
     There are no active widgets in this area.
</aside>
<aside>
     <h2 class="widgettitle">No active widgets</h2>
     There are no active widgets in this area.
</aside>
<aside>
     <h2 class="widgettitle">No active widgets</h2>
     There are no active widgets in this area.
</aside>
<aside>
     <h2 class="widgettitle">No active widgets</h2>
     There are no active widgets in this area.
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
#footer .top aside {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

As you can see on the image, the padding is still outside of the box. Firebug doesn't even show the box-sizing property on the CSS inspector.

Image: http://s24.postimg.org/x2vl2z1b8/scr.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firefox is the last browser that still needs prefix for `box-sizing`. Just add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` before `box-sizing` line, and it should do the trick.